# Apache serve different files depending on user agent

Tags: regex, apache

**My issue** I want to serve different index.html file when user accesses my website from mobile, desktop or tablet. I'm using Apache and checked that I can do it basing on user agent. I wrote code but in some cases the wrong conditions are applied (e.g. for Android with Mobile in user-header desktop version will be displayed). Also in case of desktop everything works fine but when mobile or tablet is selected, I'll receive 404. Also I'm sure js/html code works in all cases I did test it locally.

**My question** Is regrex which I used for conditions correct? First, second and third doesn't work. Also do you have any idea why I'm getting 404 while trying to access mobile or tablet?

**My code**
**httpd.conf**

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    <If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} in { 'iPhone', 'Android' } and %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /Mobile/">
    DirectoryIndex mobile/index.html
    </If>
    <ElseIf "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} in { 'BlackBerry', 'Opera Mini', 'Windows Phone' }">
    DirectoryIndex mobile/index.html
    </ElseIf>
    <ElseIf "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} in { 'Tablet', 'Android' } and !%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /Mobile/">
    DirectoryIndex tablet/index.html
    </ElseIf>
    <ElseIf "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /iPad/">
    DirectoryIndex tablet/index.html
    </ElseIf>
    <Else>
        DirectoryIndex desktop/index.html
    </Else> 
</IfModule>
```

**file structure**

```
htdocs --- desktop
                - index.html
                - desktop.bundle.js
       --- mobile
                - index.html
                - mobile.bundle.js
       --- tablet 
                - index.html 
                - tablet.bundle.js
```